# Android AlarmManager Constantly goes off

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using AlarmManager for my Timer. I have 2 classes.

In the first class (MainActivity) I am starting my alarm with the next code:

```
public void startAlarm(long Seconds) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 13141337,
            myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) Seconds);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
}
```

In another class (AlarmSound), where the alarm goes off and the phone vibrates, I'm calling my cancel Alarm method.

```
public void stopAlarm(){
    Intent intentstop = new Intent(AlarmSound.this, MyAlarmService.class);
    PendingIntent senderstop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmSound.this,
            13141337, intentstop, 0);
    AlarmManager myalarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    myalarm.cancel(senderstop);
    Log.w("Karl","stopAlarm?");
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Because my alarm constantly goes off on android 4.1.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cancel wont work. The pending Intents have to match - since they have a different context (MainActivity and AlarmSound) this cancel wont work. You have to also use getService on both.
You can

a) try to recreate a matching pending Intent

b) get the pendingIntent that started the Service in the Service and use that to cancel

But usually every Alarm just goes off once if you dont use setRepeating().

Are you sure you are terminating your Service correctly with stopself() and are giving it the right flag in the onStartCommand() Method?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I dont use setRepeating is that a problem ?  I only use the code above to start my Alarm. I also dont use a stopself and onStartCommand. I think I am terminating correctly ? How Can I make sure of that? I got another stopAlarm method in my MainActivity which works well. I am sure about that ( by testing etc. ) how Can I use that stopAlarm in my AlarmSound?

Comment: can you please post your full AlarmSound Code?

Comment: I used pastebin because I couldn't answer my own code, http://pastebin.com/cnxY8mH5 there you go

Comment: My bad, i thought you would call the activity directly. Probably your Service is still calling the AlarmSound Activity when you are calling finish() and it reopens itself. Try to call stopself() in your service after starting the AlarmSound - or try to set the initial AlarmManager to start the AlarmSound instead of your Service. I could also use a pastebin of your service if you need more help.